# When should I start a fast (upavas)?

Tags: fasting

I was fasting since from 3 Years, But today one of my friend said that while taking dinner, I should start fast after the sunrise .

Is it true?

So, I want to know at what time one should start a fast ?

Comment: Ideally fasting should start before sunrise.It ends usually the next day after sunrise.But some people fast only till sunset ie half day fast.

Comment: BTw,for all those 3 years when u used to start ur fasting?Fasting should always start with sunrise(ideally before that time).For example one can't eat the wholeday and begin fasting from sunset haha ;)

Comment: In last 3 years I m doing it at 12am to 12 pm

Comment: Sorry mistake happened 12 am to 11.59 pm :)

Comment: From 12 amm at nite till sunrise u must be sleeping.So that's not a fast. You are actually fasting from sunrise till midnite.

Comment: Yes but I eat at 9.30, so is that I am fasting from 12 am to 9.30  and is that correct?

Comment: One can't sleep during fast.And I suppose u are sleeping at nite.So u are not fasting.Fasting begins only from sunrise not from any other point of time in day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hindu fasting](http://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/hindu-vrat-list.html) is from sunrise till  sunrise the next day on which the fast is supposed to be broken.That day is called the Parana day.Breaking a fast for a hindu is as important as doing the fast.(For example not breaking an [Ekadashi](http://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/ekadashidates.html) fast within the prescribed parana time is considered an offence)

But fasting from dawn to dusk(sunset) is also prescribed in Scriptures.

I'll be quoting from the [Essence of Narada Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana13.html):

> As regards Dashami Tithi, Chaitra Shukla is stated to be a day which
>   Dharma Raja is fond of and after **fasting till the evening**, worship of
>   the Deity with flowers, fruits, ‘Gandha’ etc. should be observed and
>   at the end of the Vrata, bhojan and dakshina is to be provided to
>   fourteen Brahmanas.
>
> Bhadrapada Shukla Dashami is to observe Dashavatara Vrata to worship
>   the Ten Incarnations of Vishnu viz. Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Nrisimha,
>   Trivikrama /Vamana, Parashu Rama, Rama, Krishna, Buddha and Kalki by
>   **day-long fasting** and Brahmana Bhojana etc
>
> Ekadashi has a special significance among all the Tithis as the Shukla
>   and Krishna Paksha Ekadashis are invariably observed with Upavaasa,
>   Japa, Homa, Pradakshina, Stotra Paatha, Dandavat- Pranama and
>   Ratri-Jaagaranas followed by Dwadashi’s Brahmana Bhojanas and
>   dakshinas. Chaitra Shukla Ekadashi is called ‘Kamada’ or the
>   Fullfiller of Purusharthas and Sin-destroyer. Vaishakha Shula Ekadashi
>   is known as ‘Mohini’and Krishna Ekadashi is known as ‘Varuthini’ when
>   Purushottama and Madhusudhana are worshipped. Jyeshtha Krishna
>   Ekadashi is called ‘Apara’ to worship Trivikrama, whereas the Jyeshtha
>   Shukla is ‘Nirjala’ which is observed with **fasting without water from
>   dawn to dusk,** and thereafter treat Brahmanas with Bhojan. Ashadha
>   Krishna Ekadashi is called ‘Yogini’and is observed **with day-night fast**
>   / puja and bhojan to Brahmanas on the following Dwadashi.

So,as one can see, fasting can be both from dawn to dusk and the whole day/night as well.But fasting should always begin with the Sunrise on that day.

Allowed foods on fasting days are milk,fruits,water(in Nirjala upvasa, however, even water is not consumed).

Prohibited foods are salt,pulses etc.

Sleeping during day time,cutting nails,hair,having sexual intercourse are some  prohibited actions on a fasting day.

Hope this helps you.